# FutureBuilder before build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possibile to call the future of a `FutureBuilder` and retrieve the snapshot before the actual  build of the `builder`? In order to avoid the waiting of `connectionState.waiting`.
In code:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                       child: ClipPath(
                        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Theme(
                          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                              dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                          child: ExpansionTile(
                            
                            title: const Text(
                              "In corso",
                              
                            children: [
                              FutureBuilder(
                                  future: _future,
                                  builder: (context,
                                      AsyncSnapshot<
                                          List<DocumentSnapshot>>
                                      snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      List<String> schedineincorso = [];

                                      for (var DOC in snapshot.data!) {
                                        schedineincorso.add(DOC.id);
                                      }
                                      return Column(
                                        children: [
                                          // children...
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    }
                                  })
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'd like the data to be ready before the user expands the `Expansion Tile`, because at the moment when a user clicks on the `Expansion Tile` it shows the `CircularProgressIndicator` for a while.

Comment: You somehow have to wait until the future completes. What you want to show until its completed?

Comment: I'd like that future completes while the page is open, before the user Expand the Expansion Tile

Comment: And... that's not happening.  It'll take 1/60th of a second to get to the first build frame, and you'll need something to show at that point, because you can't wait even a few dozen frames until the internet data arrives.

Comment: Maybe I can get data in the previous Page and pass the snapshot as argument while Navigating to the Page Where there Is the expansion tile?

Answer (score 0):

If you have *some* version of the data before the future completes (like an older version from before a server refresh, or from another page, as you mention) then you can pass that as the `initialValue` argument of the `FutureBuilder` constructor. Per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), `initialValue` is the data that will be used to create the snapshots provided until a non-null future has completed.

Comment: Ok thank you. Unfortunately I don't have previous value, because i don't store data in the app, I only read from firebase.